# Can we glue CW complexes to themselves?

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space, cw-complexes

My understanding: CW complexes are constructed by inductively attaching $n+1$ cells to an $n$-skeleton where a 0-skeleton consists of a discrete set of 0-cells (points).

What I fail to understand: real projective space $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ is constructed by using pairs of $k$-cells and joining the two resulting "hemispheres" together and then gluing these two pieces together properly. Doesn't this construction break the rules of CW complexes? I have no problem attaching $n+1$ cells to lower order cells. Are we allowed to glue CW complexes to themselves though?

Edit: hopefully this illustrates what I mean by "gluing a complex to itself". We start out with two 0-cells:

$X_0=\{-1,1\}$

We attach two 1-cells, one going from -1 to 1 and the other going from 1 to -1.

$X_1=\{(-1,1),(1,-1)\}$

(Please forgive my notation, I know it's awful so bear with me) We now have a topological space homeomorphic to $S^1$. The final step is to glue either of the 1-cells to the other and the result is $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^1$. This step is what my question is about.

Edit 2: to make the "gluing" step more precise, I mean that we identify antipodal points with one another and take the quotient space as our new real projection space. This construction generalises to higher dimensions.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague without explaining the explicit construction that you have in mind. But when we talk of "gluing two hemispheres together" or something like that, it's shorthand for attaching hemispheres along their boundary (one dimension less) which is inductively part of the skeleton already.

Comment: Your understanding of CW complex structure of projective spaces is simply wrong. Which book are you reading?

Comment: Moishe: I'm reading Hatcher. Sammy: I wrote the question a bit hastily so I admit some details are lacking. I understand the construction, but fail to see why the result is a CW complex.

Comment: Then read again page 6 (Ex. 0.4) in Hatcher's book regarding the CW complex structure on $RP^n$. There is nothing there about gluing some hemispheres together. The inductive description involves attaching $D^n$ to $RP^{n-1}$ with the attaching map equal to the 2-fold covering map $\partial D^n\to RP^{n-1}$.

Comment: Moishe: the text says $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ is equivalent to $S^n/(v\sim -v)$, so this is what I have interpreted to mean gluing two hemispheres together.

Comment: @AlexS: This is true but this is not how the cell complex structure is defined! As I said, read page 6. If you do not understand the construction given there, rewrite your question accordingly. I am voting to close your question for lack of clarity for the time being.

Comment: Mariano: I think what confuses me is that there are other constructions of CW complexes that I perceive as "gluing stuff together", for example a torus is a square glued in a certain way. This is really what my question is about. Is this notion of joining points, edges, surfaces, etc compatible with the structure of CW complexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I failed to understand is that:

- $n$-cells can be attached in non-obvious ways.
- the transition from $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^{1}$ to $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^{2}$ (i.e. $S^1$ $\to$ Boy's surface) requires attaching the 2-cell in just such a way.

So basically, "self-gluing" is not permitted in the construction of CW complexes per se, but it is possible to construct CW complexes that can be interpreted as "self-glued" (as is the case with real projective space).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez What is unclear? I am happy to elaborate.